# Can't run basic example on threejs.org website

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to learn three.js, and was looking up some examples.
I was trying to run this code https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_geometry_cube.html
however, all it displayed was a black screen.

I modified the three.js source to my directory, and I also modified the material to the following, because I don't have the crate texture.

`var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({metalness: 0, roughness: 0.5});
material.color.setHex(0xc23560)`

Comment: You need to add a light source to your scene, as `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial()` affected by light.

Comment: I added the following to the init() function                                                 
 'light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
    light.position.set( 50, 50, 50 );
    scene.add( light );' it still displays black

Comment: it would be useful if you said if there are any errors in the console :)

Comment: there're no errors on the console

Comment: There are no errors because everything is correct, except the positions of the objects in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Some code with explanations:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;
init();
animate();

function init() {
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 400;
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 1000); // increase the distance
  light.position.set(300,300,300); // [50,50,50] - inside the cube
  scene.add(light);

  var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(200, 200, 200);
  var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xc23560,
    metalness: 0,
    roughness: 0.5
  });
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  //
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out, it just turned out that the material of my box is metallic, and I added the light source wrongly.

Comment: Metalness is 0, so it's not the reason, but wrong position of light is correct suggestion.